# indexing into numpy array with jax array: faulty error messages

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, jax

The following numpy code is perfectly fine:

```
arr = np.arange(50)
print(arr.shape) # (50,)

indices = np.zeros((30,), dtype=int)
print(indices.shape) # (30,)

arr[indices]
```

It also works after migrating to jax:

```
import jax.numpy as jnp

arr = jnp.arange(50)
print(arr.shape) # (50,)

indices = jnp.zeros((30,), dtype=int)
print(indices.shape) # (30,)

arr[indices]
```

Now let's try a mix of numpy and jax:

```
arr = np.arange(50)
print(arr.shape) # (50,)

indices = jnp.zeros((30,), dtype=int)
print(indices.shape) # (30,)

arr[indices]
```

This produces the following error:

```
IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 1-dimensional, but 30 were indexed
```

If indexing into a numpy array with a jax array is not supported, that's fine by me. But the error message seems wrong. And things get even more confusing. If you change the shapes a bit, the code works fine. In the following sample I've only edited the shape of indices from (30,) to (40,). No more error message:

```
arr = np.arange(50)
print(arr.shape) # (50,)

indices = jnp.zeros((40,), dtype=int)
print(indices.shape) # (40,)

arr[indices]
```

I'm running jax version '0.2.12', on the cpu.
What is happening here?

Comment: looks like it's treating `indices` as a tuple - if smaller than 32, the maximum number of dimensions.  Legacy code did this with some lists, though newer versions are working toward deprecating the behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a long-standing known issue (see https://github.com/google/jax/issues/620); it's not a bug that can be easily fixed by JAX itself, but will require changes to how NumPy treats non-`ndarray` indices. The good news is that the fix is on the horizon: your problematic code above is accompanied by the following warning, which originates from NumPy:

```
FutureWarning: Using a non-tuple sequence for multidimensional indexing is
 deprecated; use `arr[tuple(seq)]` instead of `arr[seq]`. In the future this
 will be interpreted as an array index, `arr[np.array(seq)]`, which will result
 either in an error or a different result.
```

Once this deprecation cycle is complete, JAX arrays will work correctly in NumPy indexing.

Until then, you can work around it by explicitly calling `np.asarray` when using JAX arrays to index into NumPy arrays.